# Is there a way to pick up glass after placing it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

After placing glass in Minecraft, I cannot pick it back up. I can break it but it does not go back into my inventory.

Is there any way I can pick it back up?

Comment: It's glass so what do you expect. This is normal behavior of the game. As with most blocks the don't drop or stop themselves, using a tool with silk touch with allow you to regain the glass.

Comment: @ydobonebi That is the complete answer -- you should submit it as one.

Comment: Why did mojang do that

Comment: Can't tell what's in the head of developers, but it makes sense that if you break glass, it's broken. Questions about motivations of developers are off topic here. I'd recommend changing your question from why, to "Is there any way to pick up glass after placing it"... and the answer would be "Only with a silk touch tool", and you'd probably avoid the downvotes.

Comment: Because it's glass. Why does sand fall?  And it's off topic to speculate developers intents.

Comment: And I don't submit answer because a lot a of members down vote answers only because they down vote the question. Even if answer is good complete and Correct it seems the policy is if a question is bad we punish people for helping. Comments are better and the will likely be deleted soon anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> Glass Blocks can be picked up with a pickaxe that has the Silk Touch enchantment on it.

Source: [See Trivia section in this Minecraft wikia page](http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Glass)

I believe that any tool with the silk touch enhancement will work.

You can check [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40708/how-do-i-improve-my-chances-of-getting-silk-touch-when-enchanting) for ways of getting the enhancement.

According to **ydobonebi** in the OP's comments:

> It's glass so what do you expect? This is normal behavior of the game. As with most blocks that don't drop or stop themselves, using a tool with silk touch will allow you to regain the glass.